# git clone stuck in Debian 11 while handshaking using tlsv1.3

Tags: git, github, debian, git-clone, tls1.3

The following command works fine in Debian 9 but get stuck in Debian 11

```
git clone https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto
```

Also same happens to Curl command below:

```
curl https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto -v
```

curl output in Debian 11 (before stuck):

```
*   Trying 140.82.121.4:443...
* Connected to github.com (140.82.121.4) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
```

But after adding --tlsv1.3, the curl command works perfectly in Debian 11 like below:

```
curl --tlsv1.3 https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto
```

But I can't find a way to do same for git command.